# IE10 websocket allowInsecureFromHttps

Tags: https, websocket, internet-explorer-10

I've got a  websocket implementation that I'm trying to make **work across browsers**.

At some point, we'll migrate to wss:// (i.e. encrypted websockets) but for now, it's all ws://.  When we serve a page from https that redirects to a ws host, we see the following:

1. Chrome is okay.
2. Firefox is okay if the allowInsecureFromHttps setting is set to true.
3. IE10 barfs.

I know that the correct path is to simply implement wss, but in the meantime, I'm wondering if there's any configuration I can apply to IE10, similar to firefox's allowInsecureFromHttps that will permit a ws:// link to be opened from an https:// page.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this yet? I too am facing the same problem with IE 10.

Comment: No answer to this yet...

Comment: Even i am searching for this but no answer yet..

Comment: Have you tried to enable "Mixed Content" in: `tools > options > security > internet zone > miscellaneous > display mixed content` ?

Comment: If you haven't resolved this, you might want to check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114279/websocket-on-ie10-giving-a-securityerror "It looks like IE throws a SecurityError if you're trying to open a websocket on a local (intranet) domain. To overcome this, you may disable IE's automatic algorithm for recognizing local sites. This can be done in Tools > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites"

Comment: have you tried to add the site to your trusted sites?

Comment: did you try to disable mixed secure and insecurity content block? http://helpdesk.princeton.edu/kb/display.plx?ID=9727 Can you add an apache httpd proxy with a ssl certificate to add ssl support?

Comment: 2022 Update: I checked the MSHTML source and HTTPS->HTTP websocket is unconditionally forbidden. EdgeHTML (used in the old Edge) would allow HTTPS->WS (unsecure HTTP) for localhost/127.0.0.1 only.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say, but there is no such configuration for IE10. You need to implement wss for it.

Comment: It was my experience from using Internet Explorer with automated Selenium tests that IE had very poor support for the nuances of handling HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a better way, you can guide the user to the chrome or firefox, but this is not the best approach. Try javascript if you can help.