# Client will not connect to local self-hosted SignalR server when using Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, azure, cross-domain, signalr, signalr-hub

We have a self-hosted SignalR server (Windows application) that is running locally at `http://localhost:8080`.  We also have a separate web site with a page that connects to the self-hosted SignalR server via a hub.  When the web site is hosted on my local machine, the client connects to the SignalR server just fine.  As soon as I deploy the web site to our Azure server, the client page will no longer connect to the local SignalR server.

We are using SignalR version 2.1.1 and JQuery 2.1.1.

The curious thing is that the problem only occurs in IE (we are using version 11).  IE will work just fine when the web site with the client is hosted locally, but IE will not work when the Web site is hosted in the cloud.  When using Chrome (latest version) the client will connect regardless of where the web site is hosted.

At first I thought this was just a CORS issue, so I researched everything I could find and tried everything recommended here as well as other places but to no avail.

Here is the IE console log (from $.connection.hub.logging = true) for the scenario where the client page is hosted in Azure (client won't connect):

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: comlinktestharness.html
[16:18:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url.
[16:18:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'comlinkhub'.
[16:18:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D'.
[16:18:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
```

And here is the corresponding Fiddler trace:

```
GET http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/testharness/comlinktestharness.html
200 OK (text/html)
GET http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
200 OK (application/x-javascript)
GET http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js
200 OK (application/x-javascript)
GET http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs
200 OK (application/javascript)
```

As you can see, the IE client attempts to negotiate, but the connection is stopped.  There are no errors returned back to the client and there are no errors thrown in the Hub pipeline (I have enabled error logging and tracing on the SignalR server).

Here is the IE console log for the scenario that works (when the client web site is hosted locally):

```
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'comlinkhub'.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D'.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:8080/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAL6z3nwT%2FfU%2BsVLkmYFEbFAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABBbno6Hw%2FRMgCwrkTmBB0yFdPD1pbLdlxqybV%2FIaio8QAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAC%2BS5tItVzar1XbLz2znCKXNaCnrW%2FdOYCPjFFV0HcUgDAAAACwab%2F5nGEG6iOLb2yGa8wXdQw%2Bl7T1dF60mArUv9GveCf7PpDJ6eHjlrPh3ePuRKdAAAAAkOqGRkWggu1zFBjUOXjHfW0St8EJ3EL%2B4lKNhLjFMnzh5ER48ZkaF42XN0HN3idX8834Xbp5RlFJy6ljE0npuA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10'.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport selected. Initiating start request.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[16:51:12 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000.
```

And here is the corresponding Fiddler trace for the successful scenario:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/signalr/abort?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAL6z3nwT%2FfU%2BsVLkmYFEbFAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAADwU6H8SJ5n8MePxQmgfQrUbS55oh8ENsX0QPGOufSSUQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAC6hHjHaQhxYWGrx5US2q%2FWVIcB34cfcHf0xEX1mY6AqzAAAABatf%2ByMhKKTc%2FLtakiTcuw5XIeAGczBVKQTcXHcRxNJ5my4DR9ec%2BkyBhh0us6Ql5AAAAAkZ18xiOkPzVingDTOcGOXVZziJcSUXfTYn03zIUnbuYAPj8TS5LD3LZ9s9eT4vqNwRFrQ2orA8k3dTtw5NJK%2BQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D
200 OK ()
GET http://localhost:54792/TestHarness/ComLinkTestHarness.html
200 OK (text/html)
GET http://localhost:54792/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
200 OK (application/javascript)
GET http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs
200 OK (application/javascript)
GET http://localhost:54792/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js
200 OK (application/javascript)
GET http://localhost:54792/favicon.ico
200 OK (image/x-icon)
GET http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D&_=1407448272112
200 OK (application/json)
CONNECT http://localhost:8080
200 Connection Established ()
GET http://localhost:8080/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAL6z3nwT%2FfU%2BsVLkmYFEbFAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABBbno6Hw%2FRMgCwrkTmBB0yFdPD1pbLdlxqybV%2FIaio8QAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAC%2BS5tItVzar1XbLz2znCKXNaCnrW%2FdOYCPjFFV0HcUgDAAAACwab%2F5nGEG6iOLb2yGa8wXdQw%2Bl7T1dF60mArUv9GveCf7PpDJ6eHjlrPh3ePuRKdAAAAAkOqGRkWggu1zFBjUOXjHfW0St8EJ3EL%2B4lKNhLjFMnzh5ER48ZkaF42XN0HN3idX8834Xbp5RlFJy6ljE0npuA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10
101 Switching Protocols ()
GET http://localhost:8080/signalr/start?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAL6z3nwT%2FfU%2BsVLkmYFEbFAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABBbno6Hw%2FRMgCwrkTmBB0yFdPD1pbLdlxqybV%2FIaio8QAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAC%2BS5tItVzar1XbLz2znCKXNaCnrW%2FdOYCPjFFV0HcUgDAAAACwab%2F5nGEG6iOLb2yGa8wXdQw%2Bl7T1dF60mArUv9GveCf7PpDJ6eHjlrPh3ePuRKdAAAAAkOqGRkWggu1zFBjUOXjHfW0St8EJ3EL%2B4lKNhLjFMnzh5ER48ZkaF42XN0HN3idX8834Xbp5RlFJy6ljE0npuA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22comlinkhub%22%7D%5D&_=1407448272113
200 OK (application/json)
```

As I mentioned earlier, this is only an issue in IE...Chrome works regardless of where the client web site is hosted.

Here is the Startup and Hub code for the SignalR server:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorHandlingPipelineModule());
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}

public class ComLinkHub : Hub
{
    public void SendEid(string eid)
    {
        Clients.All.eidChanged(eid);
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is the code for the client web page:

```
$(function () {
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

    var chat = $.connection.comLinkHub;

    chat.client.eidChanged = function (message) {
        // Handle server message
    };

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // Do something
    });
});
```

Can anyone clue me in on why this works in Chrome but not in IE 11?  I have racked my brain on this one and can't figure out the solution.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: does it work if you add `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net` to trusted sites in IE?

Answer (score 1):

After further research I came across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114279/websocket-on-ie10-giving-a-securityerror) that led me to a solution.  The fix was to select

Settings->Internet Options->Security->Local intranet->Sites

and uncheck "Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones".