# MS Edge: SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SecurityError

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

When I tried to load a png to canvas in JavaScript, I got this error code in  Microsoft Edge. This error happened in Edge only!

My project works like this:

> --/index.html
>    --/live2d.js
>    --/models (folder)
>    ---> /model.json
>    ---> /skin.png

This `model.json` defined the pictures needed in the model, and the `live2d.js` get data from `model.json` and make the model animate.

I just load above resources from CDN domain (https://cdn.example.com), to show in the index on main domain (https://example.com).

In FireFox and Chrome you may see a cute catoon in the left-bottom corner, but you will see nothing in Edge, and you may check it in console:

> SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SecurityError

To enable image CORS in Firefox & Chrome, I've set `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` , following [Mozilla's guidebook](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), and it really works for Firefox & Chrome, except Edge!

I see [another question on IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114279/websocket-on-ie10-giving-a-securityerror) in this site, seems pretty same as my problem on Edge, so is that mean Edge has the same CORS strategy as IE? And if possible, what should I do to make the catoon show normally on Edge (with CORS)?

I'd be very appreciate for any of your suggestion!

---

PS. You may try it here: https://u.shino.cc/stackoverflow

Step 1: Open the console

Step 2: Run commend: `iLoveStackOverflow();`

Do two steps in both Firefox/Chrome and Edge, you may know what i'm taking.

(Step 2 is reloading a new `skin.png` from a CDN domain)

---

Here's my Nginx conf:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443;
server_name cdn.xxx.xxx;    

ssl on;

root /var/www/html;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    # enables CORS
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
     }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|cur|otf|woff|svg|ttf|otf|js|css)$ {
    expires 7d;
    log_not_found off;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
}

location ~ /var/www/html/wp-config.php {
    return 404;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after a long time I'm sure it's Edge not support image cross origin, to deal with this I add a js to detect browser, if is IE/Edge, I have to load the image from the same domain...