# How to solve SCRIPT5022: SecurityError on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, internet-explorer, web-worker

I'm using a javascript file :

```
<script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
```

And it's working well on browsers except Internet Explorer as it shows this error:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2ykl.png)

on this line of code:

```
this.worker=new Worker(CoinHive.CRYPTONIGHT_WORKER_BLOB)
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebSocket on IE10 giving a SecurityError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114279/websocket-on-ie10-giving-a-securityerror)

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález it didn't help , I need to fix it for all users , Not only my device

Comment: `The client hostname/IP Address should be same as server IP/Hostname thats listening to otherwise you would get the above error.` You have to read more answers, not just the top.

Comment: Simply coinhive don't works in IE because of that. They should fix their code. There's nothing you can do as you are not the owner of the script.