# Newbie using Neo4j browser WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7687/' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed

Tags: neo4j

Today I downloaded and installed the latest Neo4j Desktop for Windows. I have not changed any configurations from the defaults. When I try to open the browser in Chrome at http://localhost:7474/browser/ I can connect, but trying to login shows the error:

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. Websocket `readyState` is: 3

When I use Chrome developer tools console I can see this message:

> 3neo4j-web.min.js:19 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7687/' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.

I found this issue which was similar but not exactly the same:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/522

When I tried this in IE 10, I was able to login successfully but then when I try to query the database I’m getting:

> Unable to connect to local intranet. This is a known error when using Internet Explorer. For more help resolving this issue [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41643700)

Following the link, it is suggesting adding ws://localhost/ as a Local Intranet website, which I did. I also tried ws://localhost:7687/ but neither has had any effect.

Neo4j settings show I am using Neo4j Browser version: 3.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried disabling my proxy settings completely in Chrome but was still getting the same error. Finally I downloaded Firefox and installed it - Firefox has an option for "No proxy" which bypasses the system settings, and that worked. There may be some bug in Windows proxy settings, which is causing both Chrome and IE not to work.