# How do I add support of vue-apollo for IE11?

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, vuetify.js, babel-polyfill, vue-apollo

I'm working on MEVN stack with GraphQL implementation. I had problems displaying my Vue application on IE11, but then I added babel-polyfill which provides support for vuetify and vue templates. Now vue application loads the vue templates but I have problems with vue-apollo.

I have tried using es6-promise and isomorphic-unfetch but I'm still facing with the vue-apollo errors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFHLL.jpg "vue-apollo errors"

Please also check if my config files are correct

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@vue/app',
      {
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
      },
    ],
    [ '@babel/preset-env' ],
  ],
  sourceType: 'unambiguous',
};
```

main.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import 'es6-promise/auto';
```

vue.config.js

```
 transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
```

appoloConfig.js

```
// Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true,
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    },
  },
  fetchOptions: { fetch },
});
```

I'm new to vue world, I'm trying to make my vue application work in IE as well, any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you mean before using vue-apollo, your application (vue + Vuetify) works well in IE browser, and after using it, the application will show this issue? From the error message, it contains the Network SecurityError, you could try to refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114279/websocket-on-ie10-giving-a-securityerror) and disable IE's automatic algorithm for recognizing local sites. Besides, here is an article about [using Vue Apollo](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/installation.html#vue-cli-plugin), you could check it.

Comment: Yes, my vue + vuetify application loads, but there are some components which are not being loaded like dropdowns and v-cards. 
I have checked apollo docs and used isomorphic-unfetch the data is being fetched and posted on the server but I don't really know why it's showing error for subscriptions and why some v-cards and dropdowns are not working but everything else seems fine.

Comment: This is how v-cards looks on chrome https://i.imgur.com/NCDhWug.jpg

This is how v-cards looks on IE https://i.imgur.com/yv9sqiJ.jpg

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Network tools to check the web request, whether it contains some error? whether you could get the data from the server side? Since this issue is related to vue apollo, you could also post your problem on [this forum](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/issues).